# stacking datafram in numpy arrays in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this,

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,22,34],
              'b': [3,49,65]})
```

and I want to add 1 to all arrays of this dataframe and store it in the 3rd dimension of a numpy array like the following figure. I want to do this in a for loop because my calculations is more than just adding one to arrays in reality. Any suggestion for a minimal implementation of this?

[image]

Comment: thanks Michael. I need for loop for a complex calculation (not just adding one in this example).

Comment: So you have to do that complex calculation repeatedly?  Then do so, collecting the results in a list.  Then make the array or frame from that.   The iteration mechanism won't make much difference in the overall time - evaluating the complex thing `n` times will dominate.

Comment: That makes sense. I have seen people doing it in image application

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,22,34],'b': [3,49,65]})
array_2d = df.values
array_3d = np.repeat(array_2d[np.newaxis, :, :], 2, axis=0)
# loop
for i in range(2):
    array_3d[i] = array_3d[i] + i

array_3d
###
[[[ 1  3]
  [22 49]
  [34 65]]

 [[ 2  4]
  [23 50]
  [35 66]]]
```

Here's @Michael Szczesny way,

([broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html))

[image]
you only have to choose how many layers you want,
for example, **3 layer**

```
df.values + np.arange(3)[:,None,None]
###
array([[[ 1,  3],
        [22, 49],
        [34, 65]],

       [[ 2,  4],
        [23, 50],
        [35, 66]],

       [[ 3,  5],
        [24, 51],
        [36, 67]]])
```

Comment: thanks @Baron, how this would be in a loop?

Comment: Like @Michael Szczesny said, broadcasting would do the job without looping.

Comment: I need for loop for a complex calculation (not just adding one in this example).

Comment: @Mike - Please include all relevant information in the question, not in a comment on an answer. Nothing suggests any *complex calculation* in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
np.array([df.apply(lambda x: x+y) for y in np.arange(2)])
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 1,  3],
        [22, 49],
        [34, 65]],

       [[ 2,  4],
        [23, 50],
        [35, 66]]])
```